# laptop keyboard is not recognized at startup

Tags: keyboard, suspend, tablet

similar issue reported in different forum threads but not exactly this behavior:

fujitsu u7510 with ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04 (kernel > 6):

laptop KEYBOARD IS NOT RECOGNIZED AT STARTUP, however if i close the lid to suspend and open it again, the keyboard is detected and works fine.

no problem with touchpad

no problem with random keyboard errors.

no suggested solution (grub acpi settings, enable keyboard, switch tablet mode, blacklisting, quirk,...) worked for me either.

i have recognized with evemu the keyboard is the device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" however there is no SW_TABLET_MODE event

enabling the keyboard doesn´t work (eg xinput enable, reattach).

is there a way do to the same thing as "close and open the lid" programmatically? (i know a dirty solution)

are there any other options to activate the keyboard?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*you also mention 23.04 thus it's unclear what you're actually asking about*), why not use the 5.15 GA kernel stack which is supported for the life of the product.  Which kernel stack you have installed (*ie. the default*) is set by the installation media you used.  FYI:  HWE is *currently* 6.2 (was 5.19, will be 6.5 next), GA always remains 5.15 for 22.04; OEM varies on your hardware/install.

Comment: @guiverc now I use Ubuntu 23.04 with 6.2, before I used 22.04 with 5.15. same behavior.

Comment: you may try one of these: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585681/ubuntu-20-04-upgrades-breaks-keyboard-mouse/763179#763179